# Any formal clause to prevent publication of my submitted paper?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

Is there any established clause to make a note of the fact that a paper is not meant to be published yet because part of the research is still pending and thence the final conclusions may prove inconclusive.

A case being a solid piece of work within reasonable framework and submission bound to happen. However, it should be secured with some kind of notification that would delay it as published material so not to prompt any rapid response.

Comment: If it's not ready yet, don't submit it.

Comment: It is ready - it contains coherent data but another part of research is still under labor and that is not a part of this specific paper.

Comment: If you want to prevent publication, why submit your paper?

Comment: @Agata Is it that you don't want any competition in the follow-up research you're currently doing? You can't have it both ways: if you want credit, you have to make your findings public. If you want to keep things under wraps, don't submit--but then you risk the original project getting scooped.

Comment: I think what's confusing most people responding is what your motivations might be here.  Perhaps if you clarify those we will be able to give you a more useful answer.

Comment: thank You, Dave Kaye. My motivation is not to spoil the workgroup's pending efforts and not to fuel the reactions based on my sole findings.

Answer (score 3):

You should only submit that which you would be willing to publish.

If you want to publish part of a piece of work, you should only submit a manuscript about that part of the work.  If you want to publish the data but say the conclusions are tentative, then the manuscript you submit should say the conclusions are tentative.

If you don't want to publish what you submitted, then you are wasting everybody's time and should withdraw your manuscript.

Answer (score 0):

Don't let anyone see the thing if it's not ready. If that means you miss a publication deadline, that's it. There's no going around it - either it's ready or it isn't. I guess that if someone had it you could file an injunction against them forbidding them from publishing it, but I don't think that would really go over well with... anyone.